# Is Position:Sticky still not fully supported on Chromium browsers

Tags: html, jquery, css, google-chrome, html-table

I'm trying to make a dynamically generated table with jQuery based on information passed to my page.

I want the top row and left column to be frozen (the way you would freeze cells in Microsoft Excel). I researched and found `position: sticky` to be what most people recommended for doing this. This works perfectly for the top row, but it does not quite work for the left column.

The left column is only frozen until it reaches the content that is at the far right end of the `<div>` that the table is inside of. If I scroll beyond that, the column scrolls away instead of remaining frozen. This behavior only happens on Chromium browsers (Edge, Chrome, all of which are on the newest versions `{Edge: 100.0.1185.29, Chrome: 100.0.4896.75}`).

My table works as intended on Firefox `{98.0.2}`, so my question is if I'm doing something wrong or if Chromium browsers still have a bug with using `position: sticky` on HTML tables (which I found they did at one point, but it seems like that was in older versions and should be fixed now)? I'd really prefer to not rewrite this with something like CSS Grid if I can avoid it.

EDIT: To zero in on one question, does `position: sticky` not work properly on HTML tables in Chromium browsers? The first row freezes fine, but the first column does not. I really just need to know if I should keep banging my head trying to get what I currently have to work or if I should start over with something else like CSS Grid.

Here is my code for reference:

```js
async function createTable() {

  let lefties = [{
      id: 1,
      leftSticky: "English",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      leftSticky: "History",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      leftSticky: "Geography",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 587,
      leftSticky: "Literature",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 1902,
      leftSticky: "Algebra",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 1234,
      leftSticky: "Geometry",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 14343,
      leftSticky: "Trigonometry",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      leftSticky: "Calculus",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 19,
      leftSticky: "Biology",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 91,
      leftSticky: "Physiology",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      leftSticky: "Anatomy",
      conditional: 2
    },
    {
      id: 100,
      leftSticky: "Chemistry",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 101,
      leftSticky: "Organic Chemistry",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 102,
      leftSticky: "Physics",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 103,
      leftSticky: "Psychology",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 104,
      leftSticky: "Art",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 105,
      leftSticky: "Physical Education",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 106,
      leftSticky: "Criminal Justice",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 107,
      leftSticky: "Photography",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 108,
      leftSticky: "Spanish",
      conditional: 1
    },
    {
      id: 109,
      leftSticky: "Latin",
      conditional: 1
    }
  ];

  let crossData = [{
      id: 1,
      leftid: 1,
      topid: 77,
      topName: "English",
      a: 15,
      b: 20
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      leftid: 1,
      topid: 78,
      topName: "Geometry",
      a: 16,
      b: 21
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      leftid: 3,
      topid: 77,
      topName: "English",
      a: 17,
      b: 22
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      leftid: 5,
      topid: 77,
      topName: "English",
      a: 18,
      b: 23
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      leftid: 3,
      topid: 78,
      topName: "Geometry",
      a: 19,
      b: 24
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      leftid: 1902,
      topid: 79,
      topName: "Photography",
      a: 20,
      b: 25
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      leftid: 12,
      topid: 77,
      topName: "English",
      a: 21,
      b: 26
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      leftid: 91,
      topid: 77,
      topName: "English",
      a: 22,
      b: 27
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      leftid: 2,
      topid: 78,
      topName: "Geometry",
      a: 50,
      b: 100
    }
  ];

  let toppers = [{
      topid: 77,
      name: "Dallas"
    },
    {
      topid: 78,
      name: "Los Angeles"
    },
    {
      topid: 3,
      name: "London"
    },
    {
      topid: 7,
      name: "Vancouver"
    },
    {
      topid: 5,
      name: "Chicago"
    },
    {
      topid: 19,
      name: "Las Vegas"
    },
    {
      topid: 100,
      name: "Baltimore"
    },
    {
      topid: 20,
      name: "Atlanta"
    },
    {
      topid: 21,
      name: "Greenwich"
    },
    {
      topid: 22,
      name: "Photography"
    },
    {
      topid: 23,
      name: "Geometry"
    },
    {
      topid: 79,
      name: "Gotham"
    },
    {
      topid: 19,
      name: "Washington, D.C."
    },
  ];

  $("#theForm").append("<table/>").attr("id", "classTable");
  $("#classTable").append($("<tr/>").attr("id", "head"));
  $("#head").append($("<th/>").attr("id", "corner"));
  for (let i = 0; i < toppers.length; i++) {
    $("#head").append($("<th/>").addClass("Header").text(toppers[i].name));
  }

  $("#classTable").append($("<tbody/>").attr("id", "classTableBody"));

  for (let i = 0; i < lefties.length; i++) {
    $("#classTableBody").append($("<tr/>").attr("id", i).attr("Class", "Row"));
    let leftSticky = lefties[i].leftSticky;

    if (lefties[i].conditional === 1) {
      leftSticky += " (Regular)";
    }
    if (lefties[i].conditional === 2) {
      leftSticky += " (AP)";
    }

    $("#" + i).append($("<td/>").attr("Class", "leftSticky").text(leftSticky));
    for (let j = 0; j < toppers.length; j++) {
      let aValue = "";
      let bValue = "";
      for (let k = 0; k < crossData.length; k++) {
        if (crossData[k].leftid === lefties[i].id && crossData[k].topid === toppers[j].topid) {
          aValue = crossData[k].a;
          bValue = crossData[k].b;
          if (lefties[i].conditional === 2) {
            aValue *= 2;
            bValue *= 2;
          }
        }
      }

      $("#" + i).append($("<td/>").attr("id", i + "0" + j).attr("Class", "ValueCells"));
      $lowLabel = $("<label/>", {
        for: i + "0" + j,
        text: "A",
        class: "Description"
      });
      $lowInput = $("<input/>", {
        type: "text",
        name: i + "0" + j,
        value: aValue,
        class: "numField"
      });
      $highLabel = $("<label/>", {
        for: i + "" + j,
        text: " B",
        class: "Description"
      });
      $highInput = $("<input/>", {
        type: "text",
        name: i + "0" + j,
        value: bValue,
        class: "numField"
      });
      $("#" + i + "0" + j).append($lowLabel, $lowInput, $highLabel, $highInput);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#classTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.ValueCells:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e6e6e6
}

.ValueCells:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #d9d9d9
}

#head {
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: right;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24pt;
}

.Header {
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 24pt;
  min-width: 300px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.ValueCells {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20pt;
  width: 300px;
}

#corner {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24pt;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  border-top: hidden;
  border-left: hidden;
  width: 300px;
}

.Description {
  font-size: 16pt;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.leftSticky {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

.numField[type=text] {
  width: 108px;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

#container {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 680px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="createTable()">
  <div id='container'>
    <form id="theForm">

    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @jahantaila I tried to zero in on one question, I hope that helps. If I can further clarify, let me know, and I would be glad to try and provide more detail.